# Minecraft server not working

Tags: minecraft

I have a minecraft server that used to work just fine. However, lately I created a small server for me and my friend to play on. I typed in localhost, and he typed in my ip.
I could join my own server but on his computer it said,

> Could not connect to server.

I thought it was his computer's problem, but then I tried 55.5.55.55:25565 and clicked join and it said could not connect. I checked everywhere.

I checked my port forwarding, and internal ip, but I still couldn't get it to work. I already checked my firewall and allowed everything. I even turned it off. I believe its because of my Internet. Because lately its been turning on and off and I can't find a solution. Please help me start my server back up.

Comment: Can he ping you ?

Comment: I dont understand?

Comment: assuming this is your server IP address ask your friend to `ping 55.5.55.55:25565`

Comment: Use http://www.canyouseeme.org/ to check your 25565 port. If you are 100% certain that you did everything right, but still can not see it, your ISP may be the culprit. And as others suggested, have him try to ping you. Also, you try to ping him (well, his router that is).

Comment: Furthermore, what is the brand/model of your router & modem. And what is your ISP.

Comment: ok i went to canyouseeme.org and it gave me an error, saying connection timed out. And i dont understand what an ISP is.

Comment: I think its lynksys

Comment: i pinged my own ip on cmd and it said 4 packets delievered and 4 recieved (Something like that)

Answer (score 0):

well it was fixed now, i decided to restart a few routers and change my ip to static, and it worked. i found that it wasn't a software problem alone, it was my hardware.